# Running commands from root directory of new workspace

Tags: shell-script, pwd

I have a shell script that cd's to a specific directory to run a set of python files. Now that I have this committed to source code management(the script and the python files) I am cloning this into a Jenkins work space and want to run the files from there. 
The script is currently written to still cd into the local repository and not the Jenkins work space therefore cloning the repository is being made redundant 
How do I write a cd command so that it recognizes the file existing in the Jenkins work space and runs it from there instead of the local files existing on the same machine

Comment: Do you mean your script has hard-coded `cd` commands, such as `cd /home/john/mywork/blah` and you want to make it generic, to `cd` into some directory relative to where you run the program?  Even better, could you edit your question to include (at least) the lines which are going wrong, please?

Comment: Exact details are proprietary so I'll try to make it as generic as possible.
So say i have a script run.sh in /home/anwar/mywork
Inside this script it does some commands plus " cd /home/anwar/mywork/tests
Then:
nosetests --with-html-out
I want to change it so that it does  cd to the Jenkins workspace which might be /home/anwar/jenkins/workspace/mywork/tests

Comment: simplest would be check for the $HOSTNAME to see if it's Jenkins host and then cd to appropriate directory or use cd /home/$USER/mywork/tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your `test` directory to be located in the same place as the script.

You can get the location of the script (irrespective of your current directory when you ran it) like this:

```
MYPATH=`dirname \`readlink -e "$0"\``
```

Then you can do, for example

```
cd "$MYPATH/test"
```

Explanation:

`$0` is the name (including path) of the script.

`readlink -e /foo/bar` gives you the absolute location of /foo/bar (resolving out any symlinks too).

`dirname` trims off the file part and leaves you just the path